# obfuscating a spring application with proguard

Tags: spring, security, jakarta-ee, obfuscation, proguard

I'm havign trouble obfuscating a Java EE application including Struts2, dwr, Spring and JPA. I just wanted to benefit from the experience of programmers who have actually achieved a successful obfuscation on such architectures.

Because of various issues we ended up switching to an annotation-based config.

I know that security by obscurity is bad and I'm conscious that it might be not worth the effort, but this is the requirement at present.